# Does SharePoint 2013 require server role "Http Activation" enabled along with its feature role?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, windows-server, features, roles

I see "HTTP Activation" at both server role and under features as well. Is it needed to be enabled under server role as well. Please suggest.

[image: Server Role]

[image: Under Feature role]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello [here are described server roles and features which need to be activated for SharePoint 2013](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/2765260/the-products-preparation-tool-in-sharepoint-server-2013-may-not-progre). There is Windows Feature **AS-HTTP-Activation** which must be activated, so I think, answer is YES.

Otherwise there can be a little differences caused by version of Windows Server you run your SharePoint 2013 servers.

*Hope it helps!*

Comment: I have checked several farms and can confirm this.